# How can EditText accept only integer

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I don't understand what to do to allow only an integer value as an input type for a `EditText`. I don't want it to input a Double or a float value, only an integer is acceptable. Could someone help me with how to do this?

Comment: put android:inputType="number" in xml of EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via XML:

```
<EditText ...
anroid:inputType="number" ... />
```

or programmatically:

```
YourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I believe using android:inputType="number" will allow it to be a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an element like this will only restrict it to a double/decimal:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

You have to use this method call to make sure there are no decimals being typed:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```